# Rails 3.2.1 simple JQuery ajax example doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm just trying to learn a bit of jQuery with Rails at the moment. I'm following the example here:

[Ideas on simple 'Hello World' Rails-Ajax Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088142/ideas-on-simple-hello-world-rails-ajax-example)

My view looks like this:
/views/main/ajax_msg.erb

```
    <div id="div_msg">
      <%= link_to "Wow",
          {:controller=>"main" , :action=>'ajax_msg' , :id=>'1'},
          :remote => true,
          :class => 'link1',
          :update => "div_hello",
          :id => 'link1'
      %>
    </div>

    <div id="div_hello">
    </div>
```

My controller looks like this:
/controllers/main_controller.rb

```
    def ajax_msg
      @msg1 = "Buenos Dias!"
      respond_to do|format|
         format.html
         format.js
         format.json
      end
    end
```

My javascript file looks like this:
/views/main/ajax_msg.js

```
    jQuery('#div_hello').html("<%= @msg1 %>");
```

My /views/layouts/application.html.erb begins like this...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
         <title>SomeApp</title>

            <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
            <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

      </head>
```

My application.js contains...

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
```

My console log shows me this:

```
    Started GET "/main/ajax_msg?id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-09 21:44:57 +0100
    Processing by MainController#ajax_msg as JS
    Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
    Rendered main/ajax_msg.js within layouts/application (1.0ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have tried many different combos by looking at other people's problems on related issues but nothing seems to work. I have tried the following:
- using $ instead of jQuery in the javascript file
- putting the javascript in application.js
- switching the order between stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag

Am I missing something quite basic here?

Thanks.

Comment: Rename - ajax_msg.js.erb

Comment: @JoeHalfFace , I've made that change already but when using '@msg1', it doesn't seem to display anything. However I tried: puts 'blah' as suggested by the comment below and I can see it in the console log...not sure why '@msg1' doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming  /views/main/ajax_msg.js to /views/main/ajax_msg.js.erb so that file can handle embedded Ruby?

For debugging and to make sure it's rendering embedded ruby you can just try doing any other string in there:

```
jQuery('#div_hello').html("<%= puts 'blah' %>");
```

I think that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, I've actually already tried renaming /views/main/ajax_msg.js to /views/main/ajax_msg.js.erb. Interestingly, I tried the code you suggested i.e. puts 'blah' and I can see that in the console log. So looks like it works. But I wonder why when I use: "@msg1", it doesn't work?? I've also tried: puts "@msg1"...console shows nothing.

Comment: can you do a logger.debug @msg1 to make sure it's getting set properly in the controller? Also, as suggested above, trying to escape javascript is a good suggestion.

Comment: Also, try `console.log <%= @msg1 %>` in your js.erb file just to see if it's not setting properly but is there. When I get stuck on something that seems simple, my first step is to try all the debugging steps.

Answer (score 0):

1) File should be called js.erb, because, obvioulsy, if you are using Ruby variable inside, it should be extended ruby

2) From Jquery API:

```
Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.
```

That means, that string should be wrapped with tags, if you are trying to set page element.

Try:

```
$('#div_hello').text("<%= @msg1 %>")
```

Also, if this doesn't work, try to escape javascript:

```
$('#div_hello').text("<%= j @msg1 %>")
```

Comment: I have already done 1). That definitely solved part of the problem. However, the msg1 variable doesn't seem to contain anything. In fact, it doesn't even seem like anything is executed in the ajax_msg action in the 'main' controller because I tried putting 'puts "something"' in the ajax_msg action but nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: I've tried $('#div_hello').html("hello world"); in my ajax_msg.js.erb file and that works. So there must be something wrong with the way I pass the ruby variable to javascript...I've also tried $('#div_hello').text("<%= j @msg1 %>"); as you have suggested but still doesn't work.

Comment: try @msg1.inspect , if variable is undefined for template, it will return nil and at list we will figure out is this reason, or some other things

Comment: it returns "nil". So somehow, even if the link_to doesn't actually direct me to the 'ajax_msg' action in the 'main' controller...I wonder if there is something wrong with my routes??

Comment: @user1988649, so you see nil? That is very strange. Please, edit server logs - how it works now, everything from moment link is clicked until the end of logs (don't do anything on website before copying not to provide unnecessary stuff)

Comment: this is what i get from the server development log after the link is clicked: Started GET "/main/ajax_msg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-15 22:08:26 +0100
Processing by MainController#ajax_msg as JS
  Rendered main/ajax_msg.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: one thing I've notice in my IDE (JetBrains RubyMine) is that it underlines the 'js' part of 'format.js' in my ajax_msg action in my main controller. It says it cannot find 'js'. This is strange because this doesn't happen in my other Models. My I not including something in routes.rb? Is it something to do with Models vs Controllers? @JoeHalfFace